# MySQL implode subquery result and use in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, implode

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE id 
  IN ((SELECT manager FROM users_info WHERE id_user = 1))
```

Here subquery in `WHERE IN ()` is returning one column and row in this format e.g. `12,13` (imploded array if IDs)

But whole `SELECT` returns only first `name` with `id` = `12`. It should return 2 rows. I was tried use `CONCAT()` function on subquery, but stil just one result.

Comment: could you describe the tables users and users_info?

Comment: is manager contain data like '12,13' a comma seperated Ids in string format, then use Find_in_Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET ()`

```
 SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET (`id`,( SELECT `manager` FROM `users_info` WHERE `id_user`='1' )) >0;
```

Comment: I was 4 sec behind then you in posting comment about Find_in_Set()